# Reducing requests to remote DB with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I think I need to build a rather complex query in a single batch.

**Problem description**

A user may ask for **data** resources from each day:

`/api/data?startDate=2018-03-20&endDate=2018-02-24&mode=day`

So first, the backend will generate ranges as follow (I am rather using pseudocode):

```
rangesArray = [
    {start: "2018-03-20 00:00:00", end: "2018-03-20 23:59:59"}
    {start: "2018-03-21 00:00:00", end: "2018-03-21 23:59:59"}
    {start: "2018-03-22 00:00:00", end: "2018-03-22 23:59:59"}
    {start: "2018-03-23 00:00:00", end: "2018-03-23 23:59:59"}
    {start: "2018-03-24 00:00:00", end: "2018-03-24 23:59:59"}
]
```

and the query would look like below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rangesArray.length; i++) {

    let query = {
      'endDate': {'$gte': rangesArray[i].start},
      'startDate': {'$lte': rangesArray[i].end}
    }

    // A huge no-no, as each request to remote DB takes some time
    let dataForRange = await Data.find(query)
            .limit(10) // Setting limit here, as we don't
                       // need to present all the data from each day.
                       // The limit is hardcoded for now but should
                       // be dependent on rangesArray.length

    // Here, do something useful with dataForRange
}
```

I need to assume that:

- each day might contain say, millions of **data** records (but I need to receive at least one record from each day).
- API will not allow querying for a longer span than 365 days (i.e. `/api/data?startDate=2017-03-20&endDate=2018-04-20&mode=day` will not be possible)
- **data** contains *startDate*, *endDate*, and (for example) *temperature*.
- There shouldn't be duplications. For example: if there is a *data* object that lasts so long that overlaps 3 days, say:`data = {startDate: „2018-03-22 13:20:00”, endDate: „2018-03-24 10:00:00”, temperature: 20.0}`, I should receive that particular record just once. I think this is rather hard to satisfy, so this is not an obligatory requirement.

So I am expecting something like this (huge pseudocode):

```
complexQuery = [
    {'$or': {endDate: {'$gte': '2018-03-20 00:00:00'}, 'startDate': {'$lte': „2018-03-20 23:59:59”}, 'limit': 10}},
    {'$or’: {endDate: {'$gte': '2018-03-21 00:00:00'}, 'startDate': {'$lte': '2018-03-21 23:59:59'}, 'limit': 10}}
    (...)
]

// One query to remote DB, hurray! But it doesn't work ...
let dataForRange = await Data.aggregate( complexQuery )
```

Comment: what is your question

Comment: @forJ, please see my edited question. I have troubles in running `await Data.aggregation({ complexQuery })`

Comment: @if you are using `mongoose` correct syntax is `Data.aggregate(complexQuery)`

Comment: Still it doesn't work. Does it work for you?

Comment: try `await Data.aggregate(complexQuery).exec()` or `await Data.aggregate(complexQuery).then()`

Comment: I am getting `MongoError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$or'`

Comment: encapsulate `{$or...}` into match so that it looks like `{$match:{$or...`

Comment: @forJ Thanks for your help but there are more errors. Maybe we should move to chat or you could post a working answer?